# js/jquery replace content within comments in head

Tags: javascript, jquery, comments, head

I want to replace entire parts of the content within my head tag. Example:

```
<html>

<head>

    <title></title>

    <!--replace-->

    ...

    <!--endreplace-->

</head>

<body>

...

</body>

</html>
```

So everything between the comment tags I want to replace using JS/JQuery. How can I best do this? I cannot find any easy way of replacing anything between the comment tags as suppose to normal tags. Any suggestions?

Comment: You cannot do that. Comment are not in the DOM and therefore cannot be accessed.

Comment: What is the objective behind removing comments?

Comment: @colburton you should post that as an answer.

Comment: I need to replace meta tags, title tags etc on the fly while reloading a page through ajax. Problem is that there are so many tags (about 20) that I don't wanna replace them one by one.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot do that. Comments are not in the DOM and therefore cannot be accessed.

To work around that you might consider something like:

```
<script type="text/template">
...
</script>
```

Instead of comments.